# Printing array in reverse order

Tags: c, arrays, recursion

I have the following source code which you will find below. I'm having a hard time understanding how interchanging the two last lines in the `printArray` function with prints the reverse order of the array.

Lines in question:

```
printf("%d", arr[n-1]);
printArray(n-1, arr);
```

Would it be possible for somebody to explain this to me.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void printArray(int n, int arr[]);

int main(void){

    int array[7]= {1,2,3,4,5,6,7}, n=7;
    printArray(n, x);

    return 0;
}

void printArray(int n, int arr[]){

   if( n==1){
      printf("%d", arr[0])
   }
   else {
      printf("%d", arr[n-1]);
      printArray(n-1, arr);
   }
}
```

Comment: typo `printArray(n, x);` --> `printArray(n, array);`, `printf("%d", arr[0])` --> `printf("%d", arr[0]);`

Comment: It is often helpful to run such programs with pencil and paper to cement understanding....

Answer (score 2):

Let's walk through it.

You call `printArray` from `main` with `n` equal to 7.

The `printArray` function compares `7` to `1`; they aren't equal, so it prints `arr[6]`, then calls `printArray( 6, arr )`.

On this next call, `printArray` compares `6` to `1`: they aren't equal, so it prints `arr[5]`, then calls `printArray( 5, arr )`.

And so on.  Compressing it down, we get:

```
printArray( 5, array ):
  printf( "%d", arr[4] );
  printArray( 4, arr ):
    printf( "%d", arr[3] );
    printArray( 3, arr ):
      printf( "%d", arr[2] );
      printArray( 2, arr ):
        ...
```

and so on.  Eventually, when `n` is 1, `printArray` prints `arr[0]` and we return all the way back up the call chain.  So, the elements of the array are printed out in reverse order (the array itself is not affected).

If you reverse the order of the calls to

```
printArray( n-1, arr );
printf( "%d", arr[n-1] );
```

then the call chain looks like this:

```
printArray( 5, arr ):
  printArray( 4, arr ):
    printArray( 3, arr ):
      printArray( 2, arr ):
        printArray( 1, arr ):
          printf( "%d", array[0] );
        printf( "%d", array[1] );
      printf( "%d", array[2] );
      ...
```

etc.  This time we print out the array in normal order.

Comment: so the diffrence when interchanging  the order of the functions, like the second example when printArray is above printf, is that it will call itself before it even reaches printf. And it will continue doing this until n=1. Am I getting this right?

Comment: @oxodo: Yes.  Then it will execute the sequence of `printf`s as it returns back up the call chain.

Comment: Imagine there are five people in a line. You them the following command, "In order, state your name and then wait for the next guy to finish (if applicable)". They will state their name in order. If you give them this command instead, "In order, wait for the next guy to finish (if applicable) and then state your name", they will state their names in reverse order.